# App crashed and Iphone Restart after saving more than 100 ekevents

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I am working on the Ekevents,my app got crashed and Iphone Restart after adding more than 100 events,this error message come when app Crash "**Receiving memory warning Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination"**

```
for (int i=0; i<120; i++) {

    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = 7*incrementedWeek;
    incrementedWeek++;
    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDate* dateIncrementByWeek = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:dateToBeIncremented options:0];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

        NSDate* dateIncrementByWeek = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:dateToBeIncrementedWeekDay1 options:0];
        NSCalendar *calendar1 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar1 components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateIncrementByWeek];
        [components setHour:17];
        [components setMinute:30];
        NSDate *date1 = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:components];
        [components setHour:20];
        [components setMinute:30];
        NSDate *date2 = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:components];
 NSDate *date22 = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:components];

        EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600.0f];
        [event addAlarm:alarm];
        event.calendar = calendar;
        event.title = @"title";

        // set the start date to the current date/time and the event duration to two hours
        //  NSDate *startDate = eventDate;
        event.startDate = date1;
        event.endDate = date2;

 //NSLog(@"optianl date1 %@",date1);
 //NSLog(@"optianl date2 %@",date2);
        NSError *error = nil;
        // save event to the callendar
        BOOL result = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:NO error:&error];
 [eventStore commit:NULL];

        if (result) {
              NSLog(@"Event created");
        } else {
             NSLog(@"Event created");


        }
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? Couldn't you create some object before the `for`, and reuse them?

Comment: Agreed!  Some of these objects are common for all 120 iterations of the loop.

Comment: yes i am using ARC but i dont think object allocation is the main issue because my iphone goes Restart after adding these 120 events :(

Comment: That's not what you say in your question.

Comment: yes i haved edited my question,sorry for that.

Comment: Well if you don't agree that the issue is memory-related, there isn't anything else to discuss.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing same issue and later found that I was adding more than 64 notification and hence the crash was happening on reload.

So after cancelling all local notifications add maximum of 64 notifications and it should work fine.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html